# How to tell if a graph is directed or undirected

Tags: java, graph

I'm working on a cs project that tests on graphs. I've come across a problem where I have to count the number of edges in a general graph (the graph can either be directed or undirected). Can anyone offer some suggestions on how to write a method that returns if a graph is directed or undirected?

Thanks.

Comment: how is the graph represented ? adjacency list ?

Comment: Yes, i'm representing my graph as an adjacency list.

Comment: It sounds like this information is part of the graph they give you. You can't tell in general.

Answer (score 6):

Well, normally "directivity" is what defines how your adjacency list will look like, i.e. should be given. 
Also, note, that `undirected` graph could essentially be a `directed` one, if you replace each  undirected edge `a`-`b` by pair of directed edges `a` -> `b` and `b` -> `a`.

Assuming you have adjacency list representing your graph so, for example you have :

- for vertex `a` you have two adjacent vertices `b`, `c`

If you are able to find edge of opposite direction for each edge in your list, you can treat your graph as undirected (or directed with 2 opposite directed edges per pair of connected nodes). 
Otherwise, it is directed. (considering example above, if for vertex `b` there is no vertex `a` in its adjacent vertices list).

Comment: glad it helped. Accept may be ?